# Android pause and resume ringtone playback

Tags: android

In android, is there any way to pause ringtone playback, play audio and then resume ringtone playback.

Using PhoneStateListener
Could stop ringtone using below code

```
TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if(mgr.getCallState()==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneURI(context,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)).stop(); 
}
```

But could not gain audio focus to play audio, audio focus request fails for below code

```
AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
           .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
           .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
           .build();
focusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)
           .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
           .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(this)
           .build();
if(audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusRequest) == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            System.out.println("Audio Focus Granted");
            mediaPlayer.start();
}else{
           System.out.println("Audio Focus not Granted");
}
```

Comment: What‘s the error message? What API Level are you coding for? Maybe you‘re not using the right API Level?

Comment: Ringtone playback pauses, but couldnot gain audio focus. No error occurs. Code for API level 26 and above.

Answer (score 0):

What‘s the error message? What API Level are you coding for? Maybe you‘re not using the right API Level?